# Conflict using elsarticle-num-names and pagebackref (elsarticle class)

Tags: hyperref, natbib, elsarticle, bibliographystyle, backref

I'm currently working on an article using the `elsarticle` [class](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle), and I'm encountering some issues with combining the `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography style and the `pagebackref` feature. My goal is to have the "Cited on page X" information along with the ability to use the `\citeauthor` command and still have a numbered reference section.

Here's what I've observed so far:

1. When using the `elsarticle-num` bibliography style, I can achieve the desired results in the reference section. However, the `\citeauthor` command is not available. See below.
   [image]
2. If I switch to using the `elsarticle-num-names` style, I encounter a compilation error, and the "Cited on page X" information appears in the wrong position. I suspect that the issue might be related to the bst file, but I haven't been able to find a solution. See below.
   [image]

I am compiling pdfLaTeX in Overleaf. I'd greatly appreciate any help or guidance on resolving these issues. To facilitate troubleshooting, here is the test code I'm using:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[final,10pt]{elsarticle}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{mathpazo} % I am using pdfLaTeX

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref} % Setup hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage{xurl}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \urlstyle{same}
}

% Setup backref
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, and~}
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and~}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}   % empty definition for \backrefalt to be used, i.e. disable standard 
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
   % alternative interface
   % #1: number of distinct back references
   % #2: backref list with distinct entries
   % #3: number of back references including duplicates
   % #4: backref list including duplicates
%%%%%%%%
    \!\scriptsize\itshape\mbox{
    \ifnum#1=1 %
     (Cited on page~%
    \else
      (Cited on pages~%
    \fi
    #2)
    } }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{prince,
    author = {Antoine de Saint-Exupéry},
    title = {The Little Prince},
    year = {2000},
    isbn = {978-0156012195},
    publisher = {Clarion Books},
}
@Article{jasa:2022eac,
  author  = {Fonseca, William {\relax D'A}ndrea and Brandão, Eric and Mareze, Paulo Henrique and Viviane Suzey Melo and Roberto A. Tenenbaum and Christian Santos and Dinara Xavier Paixão},
  title   = {{A}coustical {E}ngineering: a complete academic undergraduate program in {B}razil},
  doi     = {10.1121/10.0013570},
  issn    = {0001-4966, 1520-8524},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {1180--1191},
  volume  = {152},
  journal = {The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
  year    = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Bib Options: elsarticle uses natbib
\biboptions{sort&compress,square}
%% Fix DOI in elsarticle-num-names
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\doi}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\bibinfo\@secondoftwo
    \urlstyle{same}%
    ~\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{%
      \discretionary{}{}{}%
      \nolinkurl{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
%% Fix font for DOI in elsarticle num
\makeatletter
\let\path\relax 
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Test Section}

\textbf{Reference with several names:}
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item citeauthor: \citeauthor{jasa:2022eac}
    \item citeauthor*: \citeauthor*{jasa:2022eac}    
    \item citet: \citet{jasa:2022eac}
    \item cite: \cite{jasa:2022eac}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{2em}

Reference with one name:
%
\begin{itemize}
    \item citeauthor: \citeauthor{prince}
    \item citeauthor*: \citeauthor*{prince}    
    \item citet: \citet{prince}
    \item cite: \cite{prince}
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
% \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{example.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The error meassage says:

```
\bibinfo {author}{A.~d. Saint-Exupéry}, \bibinfo {title}{The Little\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \BR@@lbibitem.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.105 \bibliography{example.bib}
```

Thanks.

Comment: backref requires that \bibitem's in the bbl are separated by an empty line, but your first style doesn't do that. You can try this: make a copy of elsarticle-num-names.bst (under a new name), find all occurrences of this `"%Type = XXXX" write$`   (with XXXX something like article or misc or ) and delete them. Then try with this new style.

Comment: Off-topic: Please, please replace `author = {Saint-Exupéry, Antoine de}` with `author = {Antoine de Saint-Exupéry}`, so as to avoid misleading BibTeX into treating the name's "von component" (here: "de") as if it were a given name. The "de" particle should *never* be truncated to "d."

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to set the document class option `times` if you're going to clobber its effect by executing `\usepackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer, I got it working. Mico, I did the tuning in the tex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution** based on the comment by @[Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer). Thanks, Danke!

1. Copy the file [elsarticle-num-names.bst](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle)
2. Seach for all the instances of "%Type =" and replace with "\par %Type =". I found 14 of them.
3. Put the "new" `elsarticle-num-names.bst` file in the same folder of your main `tex` file
4. Done, it is working! I have also tested with an article with many references and it is working now. See below.
   [image]